# How refresh Angular 7 application remotely in second browser tab

Tags: angular, subscription, reactive, subject

My application is show some news am open same application in two PC i need to be able to refresh All screen remotely i use subject as Observable in service with Angular 7.

I tried to refresh second screen by make .next() in first screen

app.component.html

```
<button (click)="onClickRefresh()" type="button">refrech</button>
<p>{{teststr}}</p>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

app.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnDestroy, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { SharedService } from './shared.service';
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy{
  teststr: string;
  private refreshNeeded: Subscription;

  constructor( private sharedService: SharedService) {
    this.teststr = 'emptyyyyy';
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.refreshNeeded = this.sharedService
      .getRefreshNeeded()
      .subscribe( () => {
        // location.reload();
        this.teststr = 'loaded';
    });
  }

  onClickRefresh() {
    this.sharedService.letRefreshNow();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.refreshNeeded) {
    this.refreshNeeded.unsubscribe();
    }
  }

}
```

shared.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SharedService {
  private refreshNeeded = new Subject<void>();

  constructor() { }

  getRefreshNeeded() {
    return this.refreshNeeded.asObservable();
  }

  letRefreshNow() {
    this.refreshNeeded.next();
  }


}
```

Comment: I didn't exactly understand what do you mean you need to refresh the page that runs on pc by subscribing on some event that happens in another pc without making any web service or something like that !!!!!

Comment: Your browser instances are independent and the code as well. You will need a separate web services to be able to notify your application about a refresh. Ideally a push based notification service or websockets.

Comment: PankajH Please you can tel me more about push based notification service or websockets.